# Save text entered from textfield to use it in other file [Swift]

Tags: swift, textbox, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I have in two views that are connected to the menu, in one view I have a text field to enter your e-mail and I want to take that textfield text (that is the email address) to the other view, but I think I need to save that data to the phone so later when the user start the app again he/she will never have to type that address again, and then use that email address in the other view that will send an email to that address. Here is the code that I have:

```
let configCorreo = ConfigurarCorreo()
let mail = configCorreo.textField.text!
```

And then I set the recipient using that mail the user typed in the other viewController:

```
let mc: MFMailComposeViewController = MFMailComposeViewController()
mc.mailComposeDelegate = self
mc.setToRecipients(["\(mail)"])
```

But I get an error saying: "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## PrepareForSegue, NSUserDefault and Singleton

You have a few possible options to pass your data to other views depending how you want that data to be handled, I will explain each for you and you can choose which one best fit your need.

---

## [**`prepareForSegue`:** Method](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSSeguePerforming_Protocol/)

I recommend this method if you want to hold your data for 1 segue transition,  it's a good cause to pass this again to another view afterward you need to create another `prepareForSegue` within the new view. here is an example on how to do this:

First, you create 2 variables in both views, 1 to send (`currentViewController.swift`) and 1 to receive (`toViewyourGoingController.swift`).

**currentViewController.swift** `var dataToSend: AnyObject?` 
**ViewYourGoingController.swift** `var dataToReceive: AnyObject?`

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    //Check your segue, this way you can transfer different data to different view. also make sure the identifier match your segue.
    if segue.identifier == "toViewYourGoing" {

        //Initial your second view data control
        let ExchangeViewData = segue.destinationViewController as! toViewyourGoingController
        
        //Send your data with segue 
        ExchangeViewData.dataToReceive = dataToSend
    }
}
```

---

## [NSUserDefault](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/)

Now this method is good if you want to keep your data live as long as the app is installed, once the app is removed this will reset automatically. You also have the option to update the value of the key if you wish, here is how you do NSUserDefault:

I always like to register my NSUserDeafult to default setting,  a lot of people just continue with the second step without registering.

**Register NSUserDefault in AppDelgate.swift**

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().registerDefaults(["valueName": AnyObject])
```

**Set Value** to your NSUserDefault, this depends on what type of data you're storing, should match the one with your registration if you did register. (Example of Boolean data type below)

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "valueName") //Bool Data Type
```

Available types:

[image]

Make sure you synchronize once you set the value to the NSUserDefault, this way it will update instantly, otherwise it will update when it get a chance.

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

**Receive Value:** this will receive boolean value since we set boolean and register boolean.

```
let Variable: Bool! = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("valueName")
```

---

## Singleton

Now singleton is basically a global variable that you can use them in any views, but some developers experience some bugs and difficulties, use it at your own risk, I recommend this method when you're definite that you will use that data a lot (STILL RISKY), **but this method is like goddess of data handling** :).

Create a `NSObject` **subclass** and call it `DataManager.swift` (I call it data manager cause it handle data.) as following:

import UIKit

```
class DataManager: NSObject {
        
   //Store Data Globally
   static var someData: Boo! //This Boolean, you can choose whatever you want.
}
```

the `static` is what keep your data live.

Now you can store and receive `someData` from anywhere like you handle any data type like this.

```
//Store
DataManager.someData = true

//Receive 
print(DataManager.someData)
```

---

## Challenges:

You can also use

**[Keychain](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2YTlXk3Z36k)**
Sergey Kargopolov will walk you through how to use a third party to use swift keychain. Otherwise, you can take even [harder challenge](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Reference/keychainservices/) and create one yourself :P .

**[Key-Value Data in iCloud](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/DesigningForKey-ValueDataIniCloud.html)**

Comment: I think I am going to use the NSUserDefault, But I am kind of noob in swift, where should I write that code? Thanks bw

Comment: Nice, When you want to save after action, method or when something get executed. Its all up to you.

Comment: Okay thanks! And If I want to save a String it would be ".setNilValueForKey"?

Comment: For string you can use `setObject` and to retrieve it you can use `stringForKey`

Comment: So what would be the "value" and the "forKey", haha sorry for all that questions

Comment: So value is the object/value your saving, and forKey is the key to save it to and retrieve it from. It's kind of self explanatory :P

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94147/discussion-between-pixele9-and-farhad-nezhad).

Answer (score 0):

Use CoreData to save it in a database, then you can perform a fetch request to get it back out of the database.

Very simple look it up here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3IDfgATVqHw